# Google Maps in React not showing street and city names in hybrid view

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using [the example here](https://github.com/Charmatzis/react-leaflet-google) as a rough guide. I'm trying to implement Leaflet.js with Google Maps providing the base layers for imagery. Everything works great, but the hybrid view (satellite+place/street names) only shows satellite imagery-no names.

I did notice, loading it on a bad connection, that the layer with the names shows up briefly and then is buried, which makes me wonder if it's a z-index issue.

Here's the relevant part of my component:

```
...

const { BaseLayer } = LayersControl;
const key = 'MYKEY';
const hybrid = 'HYBRID';
const terrain = 'TERRAIN';
const road = 'ROADMAP';
const satellite = 'SATELLITE';   

...

export class PlotMap extends Component {
    render() {
        const filteredPlots = this.props.filteredPlots;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(mapCenter));
        return (
            <div
                className="col-sm-8 m-auto p-0 flex-column float-right"
                style={{ height: `85vh` }}>
                <Map center={mapCenter(this.props)} zoom={zoomLevel} zoomControl={true}>
                    <LayersControl position="topright">
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Satellite">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={satellite} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer checked name="Google Maps Hybrid">
                            <GoogleLayer
                                googlekey={key}
                                maptype={hybrid}
                                libraries={['geometry', 'places']}
                            />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps with Libraries">
                            <GoogleLayer
                                googlekey={key}
                                maptype={hybrid}
                                libraries={['geometry', 'places']}
                            />
                        </BaseLayer>
                    </LayersControl>
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing about the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ReactLeafletGoogleLayer component of the react-leaflet-google-layer library.

I don't know if it helps, or if you've corrected it, but this library is working fine with me. Here is the brief documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-google-layer